# Similar String Matching Algorithm : Jaccard, Dice ,Cosine and Exact

Tags: string, dice, cosine-similarity, exact-match, sentence-similarity

I am trying to find out the similarity between two english sentences. Among *Jaccard, Dice, Exact and Cosine string matching* algorithm which is the best when it comes to string matching or determining the closeness?

**Sentence 1**: Online shopping for electronics, computer parts, apple accessories, health & beauty, video games, cell phone accessories, home & garden and more at tmart.com. we provide wide selections of products at best price for worldwide free shipping.

**Sentence 2**: Shop for electronics, apparels & more using our Flipkart app Free shipping & COD.